# How to fetch the category url of the product in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

The below code is written to fetch required product details, but I want fetch the category url of the product too, please could any one help me to fetch the url within same loop.

```
<?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
       define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
       $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
       require_once $mageFilename;
       Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
       ini_set('display_errors', 1);
       Mage::app();
       $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
       $products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','producturl','image'));
       $products->addAttributeToSelect('categoryurl'); // Is this correct
       $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
       $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);

       foreach ($products as $product){

        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $name = $product->getName();
        $currentCat = $product->getCategoryUrl(); // I want to fetch the category url of the product

      }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```php
foreach ($products as $product){

    // get a list of categories for each product
    $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addUrlRewriteToResult(); 

    // get the category url for each category assigned to the product
    foreach ($categories as $category) { 
        $categoryUrl = $category->getUrl();
    }

    // get the product url
    $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Product Object  never give you category url because product  only given you categories ids.

$products->addAttributeToSelect('categoryurl');  is wrong

You need to load category object by category ids  and product will give you categories ids